# Conditions in class constructor javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have this code

```
class Person{
  constructor(person){
    this._name=person._name;
    this._age=person._age;
  }
}

class Employee extends Person{
  constructor(person){
    if(person instanceof Person){
    super(person);
    }else{
       throw 'passed object is not a valid person object';
    }
  }
}

let emp=new Employee({_name:'Uday',_age:24});
console.log(emp);
```

I want to call super(person) only when I get valid person object. I'm getting this error `this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called` in [babeljs.io](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=env&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=class%20Person%7B%0A%20%20constructor(person)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this._name%3Dperson._name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this._age%3Dperson._age%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Employee%20extends%20Person%7B%0A%20%20constructor(person)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if(person%20instanceof%20Person)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(person)%3B%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20emp%3Dnew%20Employee(%7B_name%3A'Uday'%2C_age%3A24%7D)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(emp)%3B&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true). How to make sure I pass only valid `person` object to super class?

Comment: Why should it be an instance of person? In your call to `new Employee` you are not passing a person object, but a plain object that looks like one. Also, what do you want to happen if `person` is not what you want it to be? `new` will *always* return a constructed object, unless you throw an error of course.

Comment: I want to throw an exception if object passed into `Employee` constructor is not a valid `Person` object.

Comment: So you want the example code, at the bottom, to throw an exception, right?

Comment: I think you can modify a little your super class to throw exception if the argument passed to it is null. Then, in the derived class, you check if the person is valid. if it is not you pass super(null)

Comment: You can't, `super` method have to be call in first position of your constructor. You have incoherence here, you can't `extends` from Person and not call `super(person)`, that have no sense. So you have to check this after, or in the Person class

Comment: After your edit of the question, the code triggers the custom exception. So what is the problem now?

Comment: After adding `throw` code is fine. What is the best practice to check the type of object, should it be in derived class or in base class?

Comment: That depends on whether you want the check to happen also when the base class is instantiated. But anyway, the question has now changed from "I have an error" to "best practice", so I will vote to close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code below for me. I think the main issue is that you are calling `super` inside an if statement. If `person` is not an instance of a `Person` class it will never get called, thus babel will complain.

```js
class Person{
  constructor(person){
    this._name=person._name;
    this._age=person._age;
  }
}

class NotPerson {
  constructor(person){
    this._name=person._name;
    this._age=person._age;
  }
}

class Employee extends Person{
  constructor(person){
    if(!(person instanceof Person)){
      throw new Error('Not a person!');
    }
    super(person);
  }
}

let per= new Person({_name: 'Bah', _age: 20});
let per2 = new NotPerson({_name: 'Bah', _age: 20});
let emp=new Employee(per);
// let emp2= new Employee(per2); this will throw an error!

console.log(emp);
//console.log(emp2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if it is in typescript or not, but this may solve your problem.

```
class Person{
  constructor(person){
  this._name=person._name;
  this._age=person._age;
  }
}

 class Employee extends Person{
    constructor(person){
    let temp = null;
    if(!(person instanceof Person))
     throw new Error("message");
     super(temp);
  }
}

let emp=new Employee({_name:'Uday',_age:24});
console.log(emp);
```